# Image file isn't saving in the destination directory of mern application using multer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mern, multer

I'm developing a social media application in mern stack in which I'm stuck at uploading images for new post and saving images in my folder
**Home Component (client side)**

```
import Nav from './Nav';
import LeftBar from './LeftBar';
import NewsFeed from './NewsFeed';
import RightBar from './RightBar';
import MyModal from '../../assets/MyModal';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import PrivateRoute from '../../assets/PrivateRoute';
import ProfilePage from './ProfilePage';
import EditProfile from './EditProfile';
import { Formik, Form, Field } from 'formik';
import FormControl from '../../assets/FormControl';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { useState } from 'react';
import { uploadImage } from '../../actions/UploadAction.js';

function Home() {
  const [dnone, setDnone] = useState('d-none')
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.authReducer.authData.user)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const handleSubmit = (values, {setSubmitting}) => {
    setSubmitting(false)

    const newPost = {
      userId: values.userId,
      caption: values.caption,
      img: values.file,
    }
    if(values.file){
      const data = new FormData()
      const filename = Date.now() + values.file
      data.append("name", filename)
      data.append("file", values.file)
      newPost.img = filename

      try {
        dispatch(uploadImage(data))
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="Home">
      <Nav />
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row position-relative">
          <LeftBar user={user} />
          <Routes>
            <Route
              path="/profile"
              element={
                <PrivateRoute>
                  <ProfilePage user={user} />
                </PrivateRoute>
              }
            />
            <Route
              path="/update-profile"
              element={
                <PrivateRoute>
                  <EditProfile />
                </PrivateRoute>
              }
            />
            <Route
              path="/feed"
              element={
                <PrivateRoute>
                  <NewsFeed />
                  <RightBar />
                </PrivateRoute>
              }
            />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </div>
      <MyModal id="addPost" className='modal-lg'>
        <h1 className="text-dark">Create Post</h1>
        <Formik
        initialValues={{
          userId: user._id,
          caption: '',
          file: '',
        }}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        >
        {
          (formik) => {
            return (
              <Form method='POST' className='w-100' encType='multipart/form-data'>
                <div className="form-group my-2">
                  <label id='file-input-label' className="btn btn-primary d-block mx-auto">

                    <input type="file" id='file' name='file' className='d-none' 
                    onChange={
                      (e) => {
                        const input = e.target; // Get the input element
                        const img = document.getElementById('post-img');
                        const fileName = input.files[0] ? input.files[0].name : 'No file selected'; // Get the file name

                        var reader = new FileReader();
                      
                        reader.onload = function (e) {
                          img.src = e.target.result;
                          setDnone('')
                          formik.setFieldValue('file', fileName)
                        };
                      
                        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                          reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                        } else {
                          img.src = ''; // Clear the image source if no file is selected
                        }
                      }
                    } />
                    <span>Select from device</span>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div className={`${dnone}`}>
                  <img src="" id='post-img' alt="Post Image" style={{ width: '100%', height: '30rem'}} />
                  <Field name="caption">
                    {({
                      field, // { name, value, onChange, onBlur }
                      form: { touched, errors }, // also values, setXXXX, handleXXXX, dirty, isValid, status, etc.
                      meta,
                    }) => (
                      <div>
                        <textarea style={{resize: 'none'}} className='w-100' {...field}></textarea>
                        {meta.touched && meta.error && (
                          <div className="error">{meta.error}</div>
                        )}
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </Field>
                </div>
                <button type='submit' className="btn btn-primary my-2 ms-auto">Upload</button>
              </Form>

            )
          }
        }
        </Formik>
      </MyModal>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

**Upload Route (server side)**

```
import express from 'express';
import multer from 'multer';

const Router = express.Router();

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, process.cwd() + '/public'); // Use '/' to specify the directory path
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.originalname); // Use the original filename of the uploaded file
    }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('file');

Router.post('/img/', (req, res) => {
    upload(req, res, err => {
        console.log(req.body.file)
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
        }

        if (!req.body.file) {
            return res.json({ success: false, error: 'No file uploaded' });
        }

        return res.json({ success: true, image: req.body.file.path, fileName: req.body.file.filename });
    });
});

export default Router;
```

**Upload Action (client side)**

```
import * as UploadAPI from '../api/UploadRequest.js'

export const uploadImage = (data) => {
    return async dispatch => {
    try {
        await UploadAPI.uploadImg(data)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
}
```

**Upload Api Request (client side)**

```
import axios from "axios";

const API = axios.create({baseURL: "http://localhost:4000"})
export const uploadImg = (data) => API.post('/upload/img/', data)
```

**app.js (server side)**

```
import express from 'express'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import AuthRoute from './Routes/AuthRoute.js'
import UserRoute from './Routes/UserRoute.js'
import PostRoute from './Routes/PostRoute.js'
import UploadRoute from './Routes/UploadRoute.js'
import cors from 'cors'

// Middlewares
const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '30mb', extended: true}))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '30mb', extended: true}))
app.use(cors())

dotenv.config()

// Database Connection
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_DB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
})
.then(() => app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => console.log(`listening at http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`)))
.catch(error => console.log(error))

// Use of routes
app.use('/auth', AuthRoute)
app.use('/user', UserRoute)
app.use('/post', PostRoute)
app.use('/upload', UploadRoute)
```

I've tried uploading the image and I got the success response as "{"success":true}" but still there's no image in the public folder of my root directory at the server end. Please help me resolve this issue.